# HelloFacebookSample not working, Facebook SDK update status: Android

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to get the HelloFacebookSample from the Facebook SDK working, but am having some issues. The Post Status Update brings up the facebook dialog, which looks great, but when I press the share button I receive an error, "(#404) Key hash XXX-XXXX does not match any stored key hashes". I would like to know what I am doing wrong in my process. Here is what I have done.

1) I did keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "path"\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

I ran the above from cmd, and received a hash number. This seemed to work, because everything as mentioned in the FB docs happened, meaning that I was prompted for a password and I used "android" and immediately after that I got a number.

2) I took my number, and entered it into the developer portal after creating an app called "Example". I have a screenshot of where I put it.

[image]

3) I then went back into the example project, and changed the app id to match what is in my developer portal (in the screenshot above).

After that, I thought that things would be good. But I still received this error. So then I tried to get key hash with the code snippet. In my onCreate I have the following:

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.i("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "NameNotFoundException");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "NoSuchAlgorithmException");
        }
```

What returns is "NameNotFoundException", so no key. How do I get this to work, and what am I missing in my steps? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have got the solution? please share

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is fine, I also got NameNotFoundException first time

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("KeyHash:",
                    Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("NameNotFoundException", "NameNotFoundException");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.d("NameNotFoundException", "NoSuchAlgorithmException");
    }
```

then I changed the package in `PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "MY.PACKAGE.NAME.GOES.HERE",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);`

Make sure your package name in your project's manifest file is `com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook` else this won't work.

Comment: Great! I had given up on anyone answering this. You are correct with your response. Thank you for your answer. +1

Comment: @EngrWaseemArain chal na :p